# What is the relationship between #include <stdio.h> and printf()?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()

printf();
```

What is the connection between the preprocessor and the function?

Comment: `printf()` is defined in there.

Comment: @JoeDF It's *declared*, not defined.

Comment: +1 whoops true.... wrong wording.. thanks :) ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the C preprocessor reads the line `#include <stdio.h>`, it literally reads the file `stdio.h` from a system directory and replaces this line with the contents. Then the `stdio.h` contains the declarations of `printf` and other functions, that tells the C compiler that *these functions exist in another file or library*.

When you then use `printf()` in your code, the compiler knows about this function and knows that it doesn't have to worry about it. (If you didn't include `stdio.h`, however, the compiler wouldn't have known what the function looked like at all, which could have been troublesome and the compiler will complain about this.)

An example `stdio.h` file with `printf` could look something like this:

```
/* stdio.h */

// Declaration of printf
int printf(const char *format, ...);

// And also a bunch of other function declarations...
```

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor directive `#include` just includes the source of the header files in the source file where they are included.

More information [#include](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html)

So in this case `#include` will include the source of the `stdio.h` header file in your program.

Header file `stdio.h` contains the declarations of the standard Input output functions which are actually defined in libc which is loaded as a shared library in your programs address space by the Dynamic Linker.

Answer (score 0):

The `<stdio.h>` header defines the following macro names as positive integral constant expressions:

```
void     clearerr(FILE *);
char    *ctermid(char *);
char    *cuserid(char *);(LEGACY)
int      fclose(FILE *);
FILE    *fdopen(int, const char *);
int      feof(FILE *);
int      ferror(FILE *);
int      fflush(FILE *);
int      fgetc(FILE *);
int      fgetpos(FILE *, fpos_t *);
char    *fgets(char *, int, FILE *);
int      fileno(FILE *);
void     flockfile(FILE *);
FILE    *fopen(const char *, const char *);
int      fprintf(FILE *, const char *, ...);
int      fputc(int, FILE *);
int      fputs(const char *, FILE *);
size_t   fread(void *, size_t, size_t, FILE *);
FILE    *freopen(const char *, const char *, FILE *);
int      fscanf(FILE *, const char *, ...);
int      fseek(FILE *, long int, int);
int      fseeko(FILE *, off_t, int);
int      fsetpos(FILE *, const fpos_t *);
long int ftell(FILE *);
off_t    ftello(FILE *);
int      ftrylockfile(FILE *);
void     funlockfile(FILE *);
size_t   fwrite(const void *, size_t, size_t, FILE *);
int      getc(FILE *);
int      getchar(void);
int      getc_unlocked(FILE *);
int      getchar_unlocked(void);
int      getopt(int, char * const[], const char); (LEGACY)
char    *gets(char *);
int      getw(FILE *);
int      pclose(FILE *);
void     perror(const char *);
FILE    *popen(const char *, const char *);
int      printf(const char *, ...);
int      putc(int, FILE *);
int      putchar(int);
int      putc_unlocked(int, FILE *);
int      putchar_unlocked(int);
int      puts(const char *);
int      putw(int, FILE *);
int      remove(const char *);
int      rename(const char *, const char *);
void     rewind(FILE *);
int      scanf(const char *, ...);
void     setbuf(FILE *, char *);
int      setvbuf(FILE *, char *, int, size_t);
int      snprintf(char *, size_t, const char *, ...);
int      sprintf(char *, const char *, ...);
int      sscanf(const char *, const char *, int ...);
char    *tempnam(const char *, const char *);
FILE    *tmpfile(void);
char    *tmpnam(char *);
int      ungetc(int, FILE *);
int      vfprintf(FILE *, const char *, va_list);
int      vprintf(const char *, va_list);
int      vsnprintf(char *, size_t, const char *, va_list);
int      vsprintf(char *, const char *, va_list);
```

And as you see `printf()` is defined in the `<Stdio.h>`

Answer (score 0):

The compiler needs to know what the arguments and their types are, for the function *printf()*. The programmer tells it that information using a declaration. The standard C library uses a standardized collection of header files that contain declarations for the functions in the standard C library. *printf()* is one of those, and it's declaration is in *stdio.h*.
If you're on Linux, whenever you use a standard C library function, you can look up it's man page, and find the appropriate header file to use to #include the declarations for the function you're using. There are a few categories of functions which have their respective declarations aggregated into a much smaller number of more or less appropriately named header files.